# JQuery get Java ArrayList objects

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, jsp, servlets

I am trying to get the objects from array list in my jsp with JQuery and acces their parameters. Such as name, timestamp and etc. But how I am supposed to do it when it doesn't count this items in JQuery as the type of Object I need?
Here is my servlet:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    long id = (Long) session.getAttribute("lastPost");
    ArrayList<Post> listOfPosts = PostRegistry.getInstance().getPostList(id);
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    JsonElement element = gson.toJsonTree(listOfPosts, new TypeToken<List<Post>>() {
    }.getType());
      JsonArray jsonArray = element.getAsJsonArray();
      response.setContentType("application/json");
      response.getWriter().print(jsonArray);
}
```

And here is my JQuery :

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#timeline').hide();
        $('#LoadMore').click(function() {
            $.get('LoadMore', function(responseJson) {
                // Parse the json result on somediv
                $.each(responseJson, function(index, item) {

                });
            });

        });
    });
</script>
```

And in this $.each I should be iterating trough the array I recived and this array is filled with Post obejects, so I need to get their properties for each of them so the question is: How I am supposed to get their properties?

Thank you in advance, hope someone explain me :)

Comment: please show sample of json received. Can copy it by either opening the url in browser or by inspecting request in network tab of browser console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are similar questions to yours on this site, but one possible technique would be to pass the native Java objects instead of JSON to the page, and use EL to create a **for** loop to iterate through your arrayList, pull out your values then store in hidden input elements which would be accessible to your JQuery/JavaScripts functions later, i.e.,

```
<c:forEach var='post' items=${listOfPosts} >
   <c:set var="attribute1" value=${post.attribute1} />
   <c:set var="attribute2" value=${post.attribute2} />
   <input type="hidden" id="postXXXattribute1" value="${attribute1}" />
   <input type="hidden" id="postXXXattribute2" value="${attribute2}" />
</c:forEach>
```

I've left out some of the details of how to write the values to HTML so that they're easily accessible from JQuery or JavaScript, but hopefully you get what I'm trying to show you. If not, ask me for more detail...

Answer (score 0):

Most importantly, you should be using [`jQuery.getJSON()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/) rather than the regular `jQuery.get()`.

```
            $.getJSON('LoadMore', function(data) {
                $.each(data, function(index, item) {
                    var postTitle = item.title; // example: access title property
                });
            });
```

If you don't seem to be iterating over a list of `Post` objects in javascript, debug using `jQuery.get()` to discover the actual JSON structure by popping up a message box in your browser:

```
            alert(responseJson);
```

As a side note, there's no point in using `toJsonTree()`; you should rather use [`toJson()`](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn-history/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/Gson.html#toJson(java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.reflect.Type,%20java.lang.Appendable)). Besides, calling `getAsJsonArray()` is probably nesting your results in a redundant array. Also, it's more efficient to pipe the output directly to your response `Writer`. Like this:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    Long id = (Long)request.getSession().getAttribute("lastPost");
    List<Post> listOfPosts = PostRegistry.getInstance().getPostList(id);
    response.setContentType("application/json");
    new Gson().toJson(listOfPosts,
        new TypeToken<List<Post>>(){}.getType(),
        response.getWriter());
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it heped me and also learned some useful things I didn't know :) But when I use CTRL + Space in eclipse it's normal to not show me a property?

Comment: When I click my button it triggers the print functionof the page